# How to add International SOS to an amadeus booking

Tags: amadeus

I have an integration with amadeus flights wsdl. The goal is to add international sos after a booking is processed with Air_SellFromRecommendation, DocIssuance_IssueTicket etc. I need to add the required fields to the pnr. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: For questions related to Enterprise APIs get in touch with your account manager who will be able to help you.